# File paths in Windows environment not case sensitive?

Tags: windows

Is it safe to assume that Windows local and network file paths are NOT case sensitive?

Comment: Define "safe". NTFS _can_ be configured with case-sensitive filenames, but hardly anyone does it (and those who do are generally prepared to take responsibility for breaking programs). But why do you need to know this?

Comment: @Ken, there's nothing stinky about 51%. Plenty of questions -- often the most interesting -- just don't have reasonable answers. 51% shows that this is not a user who doesn't know what the outlined checkmark is for; whatever his other faults, he clearly makes some reasoned decisions about what to accept.

Comment: @Henning, I disagree. If you ask 100 questions, and 50 of them can't be answered by anyone, either you're asking a lot of bad questions, you're asking off-topic questions, or you're not following up after you solve it yourself and answering your own question in order to benefit others. But you're entitled to your own opinion, of course. :)

Comment: I happened to see that Windows has a hacky fix of sorts now. You can [assign case sensitive attributes to a directory or a per directory basis](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/02/28/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/). I.e., fsutil.exe file setCaseSensitiveInfo <path> enable|disable. Not recursive.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes.  Windows (local) file systems, including NTFS, as well as FAT and variants, are case insensitive (normally).  The underlying implementation of a network file system may be case sensitive, however, most software that allows Windows to access it (such as [SMB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)) will automatically make case sensitive file systems appear as case insensitive to Windows.

For details, I'd read the section in the [Wikipedia article on filenames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Case%3a_upper.2C_lower.2C_preservation).

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/

Answer (score 36):

Case sensitivity on Windows is actually implemented in how the application opens the files. NTFS can be a case-sensitive file system and can happily store files, with identical names differing only by case in the same directory.

On Windows all files are ultimately opened via the [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx) API - If the `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS` flag is passed to the call (and the file system being accessed is natively case-sensitive) then the file will be opened based on an exact name match. If `FILE_FLAG_POSIX_SEMANTICS` is not passed then the filesystem does a case-insensitive file open and will open one of the files with a matching name. If there is more than one it's undefined as to which one is actually opened.

Most C and C++ runtime implementations on Windows do not provide any access to this mechanism and never use this flag so the only way to get access to case-sensitive behaviors is to use the Windows API directly.

tl;dr - Your language runtime probably exposes your filesystem as case insensitive or case preserving. You can, if you use the windows API directly, access supported filesystems fully case senstive.

Comment: "and the file system being accessed is natively case-sensitive" - can we be sure NTFS alwasy satisfy this? Is there any option to make some NTFS case insensitive?

Answer (score 3):

**NO. It is not a safe assumption.**

The other answers are informative but regardless of what they say it is not a safe assumption and continues to become more unsafe as time goes on.
[image: files differing by case example 1]
[image: files differing by case example 2]

NTFS - Can be case sensitive.
I use it on a per-directory basis but you can also do it with entire NTFS drives.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/

WSL - is case sensitive.
Linux GUI apps, and Android apps coming to Windows. They will all be running on a case sensitive file system by default, locally.