# Windows 7 / Eclipse case sensitive error

Tags: eclipse, case, sense

I have tried to create java classes in eclipse like:

asd.java and ASD.java but this gives error and lead to me rename file.. also same error with windows 7 ultimate file system.

I have looked to same question in stackoverflow: [File paths in Windows environment case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199039/file-paths-in-windows-environment-case-sensitive)

this one has good answers but I tried them not worked for me... could you suggest any thing about it. I need to implement it with eclipse urgently..

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the file name must be the name of the class, if it be public.

exemple

// File asd.java (not work !)
public class ASD {}

// File ASD.java (work !)
public class ASD {}

[Reference](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/130398/why-does-a-java-source-file-bear-the-name-of-the-public-class-it-contains)

Comment: (public final class Bp)  saved as Bp.java, and other one (public final class bP) saved as bP.java, but file system and eclipse do not allow that, How  do I fix this...

Answer (score 0):

I have find solution by using ubuntu operating system. It does support naturally case sensetive, so eclipse works just fine.