# PHP not finding class with use only on production server

Tags: php

I'm getting the following error only on production, the production env uses PHP 5.5.17 and my dev env uses 5.5.30 so I don't think that is an issue, dev env is Ubuntu and I think prod is Windows.  I'm not much of a PHP guy so any help is welcomed.

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Handlebars\\Handlebars' not found`

```
require get_template_directory() .'/handlebars/Autoloader.php';
Handlebars\Autoloader::register();
use Handlebars\Handlebars;
$handlebars = new Handlebars(handlebars_settings());
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing upper and lower case.

Comment: @Burki where, the first line is the file path that is lowercase - the rest are class names that are uppercase.

Comment: Windows is case sensitive. You might try to change the directory to `Handlebars` and see if that works. That's just an educated guess, though.

Comment: @Burki Windows is a non case sensitive environment, and neither is PHP when comes to function names.

Comment: @BrianLeishman i stand corrected. Typically it is case insensitive. But as the second answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199039/file-paths-in-windows-environment-case-sensitive) suggests, you can still get in trouble.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a case issue, I did just notice that the path is very strange any thoughts, in particular the /http.apache/  here is the full path I edited it a bit to hide the client - /http.apache/stage.mysite.com/html/wp-content/themes/theme_name/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the case of the folder path `/handlebars/` for some reason OS X & CentOS 7 were able to translate the path in PHP which was `/Handlebars/` to lowercase, the Windows Server 2003 was not able to.

Comment: That reason is that Windows file systems are not case sensitive. It isn't really a mystery ;-)

Comment: It is kind of a mystery because Windows was being case sensitive.