# Why does git complain about untracked files when none show up in git status?

Tags: git, windows-10

Git will not checkout an older version of code. It reports an untracked file:

> $ git checkout 93d5770
>   error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
>   src/app/src/main/java/com/mikejfromva/business/engine/coordinators/Coordinator.java
>   Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
>   Aborting

Git reports a clean working tree:

> $ git status
>   On branch working
>   nothing to commit, working tree clean

The file listing shows that it is cached:

> $ git ls-files -v | grep -i Coord
>   H src/app/src/main/java/com/mikejfromva/business/engine/coordinators/Coordinator.java

But the file has a different case (changed with **git mv**, I believe) in the older commit:

> $ git ls-tree -r --name-only 93d5770 | grep -i coord
>   src/app/src/main/java/com/mikejfromva/business/engine/coordinators/coordinator.java

The file is not being intentionally ignored by .gitignore. Git is running on MINGW32 on Windows 10.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199039/file-paths-in-windows-environment-not-case-sensitive

Comment: @SomeWittyUsername how does one checkout the old version under these circumstances?