# How can I get the correct text case of a user inputted file or directory in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

In my (Windows) program a user can input text and that text can be a file or a directory.

Now I want to fix the text case so that the input text match the file system case. For example if a user inputs:

> C:\PROGRAM FILES\FOO\BAR

and the directory exists with this text case:

> C:\Program Files\Foo\Bar

I want to return it with the later (correct) text case.

How would I do that in Delphi? I tried using `FindFirst` and `FindNext`, but I don't have the full path in the `TSearchRec` (of course I could split the string and do multiple `FindFirst` for each level, but there must be a better way).

I use Delphi 10.4 if it changes something.

Comment: Linking to [Is it safe to assume that Windows local and network file paths are NOT case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7199039/4299358) - with _Windows_ now supporting sub systems like _Unix_ case sensitivity must be expected more than in the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open a handle to the file/directory using [`CreateFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew), and then you can use either:

- [`GetFinalPathNameByHandle()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfinalpathnamebyhandlew)
- [`GetFileInformationByHandleEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getfileinformationbyhandleex), setting the `FileInformationClass` parameter to `FileNameInfo`
- [`NtQueryInformationFile()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile), setting the `FileInformationClass` parameter to `FileNameInformation`